# Start point for building 3D modeling software

Tags: java, 3d, 3d-modelling

I need to build a simple software that should be able to build a 3D models in a simple and a convenient way, I have very strong Java skills and thought to use Java3D or Java Monkey Engine for my back-end.
I would love to hear your ideas on how such a project could be started. What would you do in the first place ?

Any ideas and suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Some Vector Geometry/Calculus wouldn't hurt you (Hopefully that is painfully obvious!). Plan the features you want to implement before you begin, because if you go about it a certain way, it may be difficult to implement new features as you think of them. Carefully consider data structures you plan to use and what file types you plan to support. This is a large project; be prepared for it to be as much.

Comment: @Zéychin Vector Geometry is must). I am going to plan my features very carefully(design phase). I understand it is going to be a large project therefore I ask for people to express their opinions and ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest starting by thinking about the interaction model you're trying to achieve and who your target user is - having a clear mental picture of how you want to use the system will help you maintain focus.

For example, do you imagine your editing process being one wherein you build your 3d objects up by combining 'primitive' objects like cuboids, spheres, cylinders and so on through an approach referred to as [Constructive Solid Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) adding, subtracting or intersecting three dimensional volumes from each other.

Or, do you see yourself taking an approach like that offered by [Rhino3d](http://www.rhino3d.com) (among many others that's just one I happen to enjoy working in) wherein you can draw curves and perform operations such as revolving around an axis to create a surface of revolution, or lofting curves along a path to create a surface, extruding to give surfaces volume and so on.

Or do you envisage a deformation approach, wherein you start with a 3d shape which you then sculpt like virtual clay by pulling or repelling points on the surface in a particular direction.

Your choice of modelling approach will make some things easier to model (and to code) and other things harder. You can aim to include several different modelling methods in a single app, but focusing on one to start with should help you make progress.

If you haven't used many modelling applications, then I would suggest downloading a few trial versions of applications and seeing what approach suits you the best.

You should also consider whether you are going to focus on creating and editing polygon meshes, and so can focus on creating tools to operate on meshes, or whether you are going to model using parametric surfaces.

Comment: I will use real time data gloves and kinect to get accurate hand position, I will use the deformation approach, could you suggest me any good book on how to use this approach.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any books specifically covering modelling using that technique, but a basic implementation would involve taking a mesh and then attracting or repelling points in that mesh based on the position of your modelling tool (fingertips) in relation to nearby points in the model, in proportion to the distance between the tool and the point, along the vector between them. If the number of points in the object is too low that won't look great, so you could look online at topics like Adaptive subdivision to add extra points to the mesh in the areas you want to deform.